# Magento: dependant upsell product

Tags: php, html, magento, e-commerce

I'm trying to allow for a product to have an up-sell ... but I don't want to be able to add just the up-sell item only to the cart ... it only makes sense as an "extension" to a specific product.

```
Concert Ticket = $50.00 ... but if you get the VIP pass, it's $50.00 + $100.00
```

Maybe an up-sell product isn't what I need, but I don't know what my options are. Perhaps just create another product for the $50.00 ticket, but name it VIP Ticket and have it's cost as $150.00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a good instance for adding a Custom Option on the product.

Have your concert ticket as the base product.

Add a custom option (via drop down or checkbox) that provides the ability to add a VIP Pass at $100.

Comment: The only problem with that is I can't have a lengthy description... I can't have a description at all for that option specifically.